# get Element by ID using DOM parser in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an XML file which is structured like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry id="young_1">
  <sense n="1">
     <cit type="translation" lang="fr">
        <quote>jeune</quote>
      </cit>
      <re type="phr">
         <sense>
           <cit type="translation" lang="fr">
              <quote>un jeune homme</quote>
           </cit>
          </sense>
      </re>
  </sense>
  <sense n="2">
    <cit type="translation" lang="fr">
        <quote>petits
            <hi rend="i">mpl</hi>
        </quote>
  </sense>
</entry>
```

I need to parse it using JAVA to obtain each `quote` value contained in a `cit` element with the attribute `type="translation"` :

- I just need to have the text content of the `quote` element but I don't need to have the text content of the immediate node such as `<quote>petits <hi rend="i">mpl</hi></quote>`
- I don't need to have the text content of the `quote` element contained in an `re` element

Finally I need to obtain this result:

```
entry ==> young_1
  translations ==> [jeune;petits]
```

For now my JAVA code is:

```
    //load xml document for DOM parsing
    Document doc = loadXMLFromString(xmlContent);

    //now try to parse it
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("sense");
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(i);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                NodeList fieldNodes = eElement.getElementsByTagName("cit");
                for(int j = 0; j < fieldNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node fieldNode = fieldNodes.item(j);
                    NamedNodeMap attributes = fieldNode.getAttributes();
                    Node attr = attributes.getNamedItem("type");
                    if(attr != null) {
                        if(attr.getTextContent().equals("translation")) {
                            //how can I access <quote> element ???
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But I don't know how can I access the `<quote>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `<quote>` element exactly the same way you're accessing the `<cit>` elements: by using the `Element#getElementsByTagName(String name)` method:

```
Node attr = attributes.getNamedItem("type");
if (attr != null) {
    if (attr.getTextContent().equals("translation")) {
        Element citElement = (Element) fieldNode;
        NodeList quoteNodeList = citElement.getElementsByTagName("quote");
        if(quoteNodeList.getLength() > 0) {
            Node quoteNode = quoteNodeList.item(0);
            String quote = quoteNode.getTextContent();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In order to exclude nodes contained in a `<re>` node, you can check the parent of the `<sense>` node using `nNode.getParentNode().getNodeName()`, e.g.:

```
 if (!nNode.getParentNode().getNodeName().equals("re")) {
       ....
 }
```

Comment: It works not bad but I just need to get the text content `jeune` and `petits`. I have modify my initial answer to details my example.

Comment: To solve the problem of the `quote` element I've used       `String quote = quoteNode.getFirstChild().getTextContent();` but for now I always have a problem with the `cit` element contained in `re`

Comment: @ChesterMcAllister Basically your program can get all nodes of name `cit` and check if their "grandfather" nodes are not `re` nodes (using the method `Node#getParentNode()`).